# What evidence do we have for S-duality in N=4 Super-Yang-Mills?

Tags: research-level, supersymmetry, yang-mills, lattice-model, duality

Do we have anything resembling a proof*? Or is it just a collection of "coincidences"?

Also, do we have evidence from lattice gauge theory computations?

*Of course I'm not talking about a proof in the mathematical sense, only a compelling albeit heuristic argument e.g. an argument involving formal manipulations with path integrals.

Comment: Just a quick feedback: I doubt there is something resembling a proof in a mathematical sense of anything at all for a fully fledged QFT (which has infinitely many states and divergences -- leading to non-trivial critical exponents), so I am not sure this is productive. Asking for evidence seems interesting though a bit broad, maybe there is a place to add some motivation. I am also  not sure by what you mean by “numerical” and why you single out such evidence.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a "proof" of S-duality in free abelian gauge theory. See, for example, Witten's [On S-Duality in Abelian Gauge Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9505186) or his [IAS lecture](http://www.math.ias.edu/QFT/spring/witten8-II.ps). Morally, you should think of this as a Fourier transform. The non-Abelian version, of course, is much harder and requires N=4 SUSY. But this isn't a surprise as the non-Abelian Fourier transform is a tricky thing.

Now, at least from the math side, you should be thinking about [Geometric Langlands](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+Langlands+program) which is pretty closely related and has the same distinction between the Abelian case (which I understand to reduce to some class field theory stuff) and the more difficult non-Abelian version. Long before Kapustin-Witten and all that has come after, this connection was first shown in [Harvey, Moore and Strominger](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9501022v2)  and [Bershadsky, Johansen, Sadov and Vafa](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9501096v1).

There is, of course, a long, long list of "coincidences", too.

Comment: Geometric Langlands is very close to being proved nowadays. However, it only has to do with the topological part of the gauge theory - I don't think there is a mathematical approach to non-supersymmetric observables.

Comment: Definitely (and other topological twists also evince S-duality, i.e., Vafa and Witten's hep-th/9408074). The point was to draw the analogy between the Abelian and non-Abelian Fourier transform as the desired heuristic.

Comment: Welcome, Aaron!

Comment: I must be thoroughly confused. Isn't the Abelian case just ordinary electric-magnetic duality? If so, it just acts as the Hodge star on the field strength tensor. How does Fourier transform enter the picture?

Comment: The complex coupling goes from g->-1/g. It's much the same as the R->1/R T-duality.

Comment: Right, so how does it relate it to Fourier transform?

Comment: The short answer is that it's a closely related to Abelian duality which mathematically is related to a Fourier-Mukai transform.

Comment: This should remind you a lot of Poisson resummation, too.

Comment: Are you sure that the geometric Langlands program is close to being proved? I've always been under the impression that it would occupy mathematicians for generations to come...

Comment: Geometric Langlands is, in large parts, proved. Langlands for number fields is much harder.